# application after building --prod --release is only on the splashscreen ionic 3

Tags: android, angular, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3

after updating to cordova 9, and run the command `ionic cordova build android --prod - release` application only in splashcreen. but when run `ionic cordova run android --prod` run as well. 
I was confused because no error appeared.

```
   Ionic CLI          : 5.4.5 (C:\Users\joko\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic)
   Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.9
   @ionic/app-scripts : 3.2.4

Cordova:

   Cordova CLI       : 9.0.0 (cordova-lib@9.0.1)
   Cordova Platforms : android 8.1.0, browser 6.0.0
   Cordova Plugins   : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.2.0, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 4.1.3, (and 26 other plugins)

Utility:

   cordova-res : 0.9.0 (update available: 0.11.0)
   native-run  : 0.2.9 (update available: 0.3.0)

System:

   Android SDK Tools : 24.4.1 (C:\Users\joko\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk)
   NodeJS            : v10.16.3 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe)
   npm               : 6.9.0
   OS                : Windows 10
```

Comment: Hi Joko Did u try 'ionic serve' to check for any errors on the console?

Comment: no error.  run on  emulator also no problem

Comment: use google chrome://inspect to see the error and add it to your question

Comment: halo Ali, no error on chrome://inspect